# Why can't Qt Creator find the Windows 10 SDK headers?

Tags: qt, visual-c++, windows-10, qt-creator, visual-studio-2019

I've installed Qt 5.14.2 with 64-bit MSVC libraries and Qt Creator 4.12.1. When I attempt to build any of the example projects, I get the following error:

```
C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stddef.h': No such file or directory.
```

I've already installed Visual Studio, along with UCRT and the Windows 10 SDK. I've verified that `stddef.h` does in fact exist inside the SDK. The problem appears to be that `vcvarsall.bat` (or `vcvars64.bat`) does not add the include directories for the SDK.

Here are the environment variables that are assigned by `vcvars64.bat`:

```
CommandPromptType=Native                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
DevEnvDir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\
ExtensionSdkDir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Kits\10\ExtensionSDKs
Framework40Version=v4.0
FrameworkDir=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\
FrameworkDir64=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\
FrameworkVersion=v4.0.30319
FrameworkVersion64=v4.0.30319
INCLUDE=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\ATLMFC\include;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\include;
LIB=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\ATLMFC\lib\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\lib\x64;
LIBPATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\ATLMFC\lib\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\lib\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\lib\x86\store\references;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319;
Path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\\Extensions\Microsoft\IntelliCode\CLI;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\HostX64\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCPackages;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\bin\Roslyn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual…
Platform=x64
VCIDEInstallDir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\
VCINSTALLDIR=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\
VCToolsInstallDir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\
VCToolsRedistDir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Redist\MSVC\14.26.28720\
VCToolsVersion=14.26.28801
VisualStudioVersion=16.0
VS160COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\Tools\
VSCMD_ARG_app_plat=Desktop
VSCMD_ARG_HOST_ARCH=x64
VSCMD_ARG_TGT_ARCH=x64
VSCMD_VER=16.6.0
VSINSTALLDIR=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\
WindowsLibPath=References\CommonConfiguration\Neutral
WindowsSDKLibVersion=winv6.3\
WindowsSDKVersion=\
__DOTNET_ADD_64BIT=1
__DOTNET_PREFERRED_BITNESS=64
__VSCMD_PREINIT_PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Perforce;C:\Program Files\ServiceNow;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\[REDACTED]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Users\[REDACTED]\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\[REDACTED]\AppData\Roaming\npm
__VSCMD_script_err_count=0
```

`stddef.h` is in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt`, but that path is not added to `INCLUDE`.

How is Qt Creator supposed to find the Windows SDK?

Comment: Did the SDK recently get upgraded?

Comment: for me I have WindowsSDKVersion=10.0.18362.0\ however I am holding off VS updates at work.

Comment: @drescherjm I'm not sure what you mean. This is a brand new install of both Visual Studio and Qt. I did not have this already working with a previous version.

Comment: Could be a bug in 16.6

Comment: For me 16.5.5 does not have this `WindowsSDKVersion=\` bug either. You may want to try installing the earlier version and don't let it upgrade.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/history#installing-an-earlier-release

Comment: I just read that you can't go back for community versions. I assume you are using that.

Comment: Yes, I am using Community.

Comment: Had the same problem, this fixed it for me: messing with environment variables under build settings, thinking that the `LIB` value pointed to a nonexistent folder. I then proceeded by writing half a stackoverflow answer, before realizing that I was mixing up `libs` and `include` and that the paths were correct all along. I then reset my changes, and voila, it was building again! 
Then some cursing on spending three hours on this problem, and learning nothing. Some of the steps might not have contributed a lot though!

Comment: @5nefarious I'm having the exact same problem. Did you solve it yet?

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the exact same problem.
It's working in Visual Studio 2019 but not in Qt Creator and neither on the commandline.

The reason for my problem was missing rights to access the registry. To get some hints on your side just run the following:

```
set VSCMD_DEBUG=3
vcvars64.bat > log.txt
```

My output were multiple of these errors:

```
"ERROR: Registry editing has been disabled by your administrator."
```

Checking `log.txt` one could see that it was indeed not setting `WindowsSdkDir` properly.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, I don't know the exact cause but the workaround I followed is (I am building using QtCreator) adding following to .pro file.

```
INCLUDEPATH += "C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10/shared"
INCLUDEPATH += "C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10/um"
INCLUDEPATH += "C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10/ucrt"
LIBS += -L"C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Lib/10/ucrt/x64"
LIBS += -L"C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Lib/10/um/x64"
```